# parsing file on a specified string

Tags: c#, parsing, lambda

I wrote the code below to parse a file that has the format below.

Please let me know if I can clean up that code preferably writing lambda expressions instead of the for loops.

The code in the method already has already the contents of the file in a StringBuilder variable using the StreamReader class.

**Format**

[image]

**Code**

parser from the calling function is equal to "Other Total"

```
private void ParseObject(StringBuilder body, string parser)  
{
    List<string> lines = body.ToString().Split(Convert.ToChar(Helper.newLine)).ToList();
    List<string> pages = new List<string>();

    body.Length = 0;

    int counter = 0;
    int startPosition = 0;

    for (int i = startPosition; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains(parser))
        {

           counter = i + 1;
           for (int j = startPosition; j < counter; j++)
           {
              if (!lines[j].Contains(Helper.lineFeed))
              {
                  body.Append(string.Concat(lines[j], Helper.newLine));
              }
           }

           startPosition = counter;
           pages.Add(body.ToString());
           body.Length = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The returning strings looks like this:

**pages[0]**

[image]

**pages[ 1]**

[image]

Comment: So you are just splitting the input string in so called _pages_ after the string _Other Total:XXXX_  ?

Comment: @Steve: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can just use the overload of IndexOf that take a previous starting position to loop over the string splitting it at the first newline after the "Other Total:" string.

```
private List<string> ParseObject(StringBuilder body, string parser)
{
    List<string> pages = new List<string>();

    string data = body.ToString();
    int splitPos = 0;
    int startPos = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // Search the position of the parser string starting from the
        // previous found pos
        int parserPos = data.IndexOf(parser, splitPos);
        if (parserPos != -1)
        {
            // Now we search the position of the newline after the 
            // found parser pos
            splitPos = data.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, parserPos);

            // Take the substring starting from the previous position up to
            // the current newline position 
            pages.Add(data.Substring(startPos, splitPos - startPos).Trim());

            // reposition to the new starting position for IndexOf
            startPos = splitPos;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return pages;
}
```

And you call it with

```
var result = ParseObject(input, "Other Total:");
```

Notice that you should return the pages list, otherwise the call is useless

Comment: Didn't even think of doing it this way..Will try it out and get back with the results.

Comment: Getting a length cannot be 0 error.  startPos = 0 and splitPos = -1.  Should there be another condition in the if statement that splitPos != - 1?  Also, I'm returning List<string> from the ParseObject.  But I didn't include it as I'm calling another method in ParseObject that's irrelevant to my question.

Comment: I am not sure how is defined your Helper.newline. Try to replace the Environment.NewLine with your Helper.newline.

Comment: Using Helper.NewLine worked.  Very cool how you used the overload method of IndexOf and how you thought of getting the next line after the parser.  Logically, that's how I wanted to do it, but couldn't think how to code it.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Regex approach:

Test: https://regex101.com/r/HP1ufT/1/

```
List<string> pages = new List<string>();

string pattern = @"^(.*?Other Total:.*?)$";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(lines, pattern,
  RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    pages.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```